# Android, using appropriate intent flags

Tags: android, android-intent, flags

It is the first time I try to use intent flags in up navigation, and I am getting confused which are the right intent flags to use. My application tree is:

```
  A    
 / \   
B   S   
|   |   
C   W   
|   |   
D   D
```

The main activity is A, S is a searchable activity. The state of activity S and W are saved. When navigating up from D, it goes to C, then B and A. It is the same for S, W, D.

My best approach is using: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);` in all intents. Everything works ok in 2.3.3 but when I try in 4.2 activities are destroyed when navigating up. For example, when I go: A-S-W then I navigate up to S, S is resumed. The problem occus in this scenario: A-S-W-D then navigate up to W. In this case W and S are destroyed and A is resumed. The same happens in this other case: A-B-C then navigating up brings to B, and when A-B-C-D then navigating up brings to A.

As far as I understand, using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP finishes the calling activity and if the called activity is in the stack, it doesnt create a new instance. But this is not happening.

So why the activities are destroyed? Which are the correct flags to use in this simple case?